# Multiple ENOENT errors while restoring node packages

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm trying to install node dependencies for my react project that i downloaded from source control but having some troubles.For instance I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to compile
./node_modules/chain-function/index.js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\....\v7\ClientApp\node_modules\chain-function\index.js'
```

I do not have "chain-function" a listed as dependency in my package.json file, and i'm not sure how to figure out what is causing the error here and how to troubleshoot it.

here is my package.json dependencies:

```
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"popper.js": "^1.14.4",
"react": "^16.5.2",
"react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
"react-cookie": "^3.0.4",
"react-dom": "^16.0.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"react-scripts": "^2.0.4",
"react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
"react-tooltip": "^3.9.0",
"react-transition-group": "^2.5.0",
"redux": "^4.0.0",
"rimraf": "^2.6.2"
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that some of your dependency in package.json rely on chain-function or it's just the problem with the network.It's normal to face a problem like this.I can only give you some advices.

---

1. delete your node_modules,run "npm install" again
2. download the project in another directory folder, and try it again
3. check your network